# Displaying photos in the gallery app given filename

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-image, android-gallery

I am trying to display multiple images in the default gallery app. I am able to display one with

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("insert_filename_here"), "image/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

But I want to open multiple. I asked this question before and was linked to other threads, but the answers are just how to SELECT multiple images. I just want to display them. I found an answer for if they are in the same folder, but my folder has other images that I don't want to display. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> I am able to display one with

First, that does not necessarily have anything to do with "the default gallery app". It will open whatever the user wants, among whatever apps are installed that support `ACTION_VIEW` for a MIME type of `image/*` and for whatever scheme is in that `Uri`.

Second, there is no single "default gallery app". There are dozens, if not hundreds, of "default gallery app" implementations across the thousands of device models and ~2 billion Android devices.

> But I want to open multiple

You will have to write your own UI for this.

> I found an answer for if they are in the same folder

There is no requirement that any Android device have any application capable of displaying multiple images at a time. And there is no standard `Intent` structure for requesting to view more than one thing.